# Convolution of a discrete signal $f$ with $g$ computing the centered finite difference derivative of $f$

Tags: calculus, signal-processing

I have the following discrete signal with 8 samples:

$f[x]=[1,2,1,0,1,0,-1,-2]$

I need to find a $g$ such that convolution of the discrete signal above with $g$ computes the centered finite difference derivative of $f$ with step length $1$.

However, I'm quite lost here, and need some help/hints.

Comment: Is g= [-1 +1] the solution to your problem?

Comment: That is not specified, so i'm not sure

Comment: Try it! The sequence isn’t very long.

Comment: That gives me $[-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -2]$, but i'm not sure what that means.

Comment: What do YOU think the derivative is at each value?

Comment: I found out why it is $g=[-1,1]$. Thank you for the help